# Suggestion for books tracing the evolution of photographic equipment

Tags: lens-design, shutter, history, technology-generations

Could you please suggest a book that

1. Tracks the evolution of photo equipment from inception to modern times
2. Has diagrams and cutaways of equipment and mechanisms, including shutter and aperture mechanisms and lens design
3. Includes notes on the thinking (the engineering) that made the evolution possible

Comment: Answers are probably best as community wiki & one book per answer? Just my suggestion.

Comment: @Unapiedra In general, those don't work very well -- we get a few good suggestions and then an unmaintained list, just creating more of http://meta.photo.stackexchange.com/questions/1833/how-should-we-handle-community-wiki-pages-which-are-a-big-mess

Comment: As useful and interesting as this might seem, I really think it's the wrong fit for the Q&A format. Basically, it's just too broad.

Comment: Books on history of anything are not easily going out of date, unless they are about too recent history to be accurate and not fully covering the subject. I believe history of camera technology should be a stable enough subject and those books are therefore not going out of date anytime soon.

Comment: It's not that the books get out of date, it's that there are _too many books_. Although, actually, books fall out of print all the time, and new books come out.

Comment: There's a wikipedia page about history of photography too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An excellent book for lens information is, 
"[A History of the Photographic Lens](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0124086403)" by Rudolph Kingslake.

Comment: Ah, this is awesome, thanks. It's exactly what I was looking for! If you could add a book that does the same for camera mechanisms (shutters etc) I would like to mark this as the answer!

Comment: Kaushik, an article available on-line about shutters is available here: http://randcollins.wordpress.com/2010/08/01/shutters/ .There are a few useful links at the end of the article.

Comment: That article has excellent references too. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Roger Cicala wrote about certain historical aspects of camera and lens history on his blog on Lensrentals: 
http://www.lensrentals.com/blog/category/photography/history

Answer (score 0):

Here are some books you can check:

- ["The History of Photography: From 1839 to the Present"](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0870703811) by
  Beaumont Newhall
- ["A World History of Photography"](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0789209373) by Naomi Rosenblum
- ["History and Practice of Art and Photography"](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1475178786) by Henry Hunt
  Snelling

Comment: Hi @Jez, do these slant towards the technical side of things, and do they have technical illustrations/drawings? Thanks!